# Profile Access to Activity Custom Fields via git

Tags: permissions, profile, git, jenkins

I have a added a custom field in Activity object and gave read only access to a specific profile. We are having git and Jenkins to deploy these files. Below is the profile definition with adding the permissions.

```
<fieldPermissions>
     <editable>false</editable>
     <field>Event.field__c</field>
     <readable>true</readable>
</fieldPermissions>

<fieldPermissions>
     <editable>false</editable>
     <field>Task.field__c</field>
     <readable>true</readable>
</fieldPermissions>
```

Somehow this doesnt reflect on target org. Do i need to do anything else?

Comment: Are you able to confirm what it actually deployed (ex. included the profile file, not only the custom field)? How are you confirming it doesn't reflect on that target org?

Comment: Yes I sent the custom fields together with the profile. I cross checked the target org object permissions to confirm